# Is there a way of checking more than one condition in Swift switch?

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement

In Swift, I need to make a switch like this:

```
switch char {
    case "+": statement 1; statement 3
    case "-": statement 2; statement 3
 default: statement 3   
}
```

However, I don't want to copy the statement 3, because it is actually quite long, so I'm looking for an alternative way (if it exists) to somehow make the switch check every case condition, and execute the default too.

Comment: Why not just execute statement 3 after the switch finishes? (not in each case) Put `break` in the default case

Comment: Thank you Okapi, good thought, but I actually have some more cases in that switch, I chose not to write them to make my question more simple and clean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Repeated code? Good candidate for a local function:

```
func statement3() {
    // ... lots of stuff here ...
}
switch char {
    case "+": statement 1; statement3()
    case "-": statement 2; statement3()
 default: statement3()   
}
```

But if you *really* want to do `statement3` in *every* case, then just take it out of the switch statement altogether:

```
switch char {
    case "+": statement 1
    case "-": statement 2
 default: break   
}
statement 3
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can fallthrough a case and skip over the next one to get you to default is to retest the condition:

```
switch char {
case "+": statement 1; fallthrough
case "-": if char == "-" { statement 2 }; fallthrough
default: statement 3
}
```

which at the end of the day, let's be honest, looks awesomely frugly. I suggest you replace your long statements by function calls and keep the control flow you gave above.